# Can i delete windows 7 on a hard drive and keep my stuff and then access it on a new windows 7 on an ssd?

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, ssd

Qk let's say I have a hard drive with windows 7 and all my other stuff on it. I later buy a new SSD to put my Operating System on it.

1. Can I delete windows 7 on the hard drive and keep the rest of my stuff?
2. After that can I download a fresh copy of windows 7 on to the SSD. Can I still access my old 
   info from my hard drive?

Comment: Why would you delete Windows on the hdd if you have things on the hdd you want to save?  Backup up those things before you do anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can try connecting your old hard drive to your computer as a *primary slave*. I won't go into too much detail about this since this varies from computer to computer.

You can delete the Windows folder in your old hard drive and have your SSD contain Windows and all of your programs. However, you will have to reinstall those programs. After you do that, you can just clean up the old drive, leaving only your files and plenty of space to work with.

Your other option is to [clone your old hard drive to your SSD](http://lifehacker.com/5837543/how-to-migrate-to-a-solid+state-drive-without-reinstalling-windows). This may come out a bit problematic, but it could save you a lot of time later.

Comment: I would: 1. make copy od user folder (in Users) 2. install new Windows 3. install all apps that were on the previous installation 4. put back the user folder copy in the same place

Answer (score 0):

Assuming if you have two partitions namely C and D drives respectively,you can move your contents to D drive,then install your OS on C drive and then you can access.
But if you have only one drive and if you try to do so then it is not advisable.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Can I delete windows 7 on the hard drive and keep the rest of my stuff?

Sure you can, of course you can't delete a copy of windows while you are running it but you can certainly delete it after connecting the hard drive as a secondary drive.

> After that can I download a fresh copy of windows 7 on to the SSD. Can I still access my old info from my hard drive?

Generally yes. In some cases it may be necessary to fiddle with file permissions to get around access denied errors.

To make sure there is no confusion I recommend disconnecting the hard drive and connecting the new SSD to the first SATA port. Then after doing the new install of windows attatch the hard drive to a higher numbered SATA port.